# How to shorten this nginx try_files config?

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx config as below:

```
location / {
    index home.html index.html;
}

location ~ ^/t/(.*)/(.*)/index {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /t/$1/$2/index.html;
}

location ~ ^/t/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /t/$1/$2/index.html;
}

location ~ ^/t/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /t/$1/$2/index.html;
}

location ~ ^/t/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /t/$1/$2/index.html;
}

location ~ ^/t/(.*)/(.*)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /t/$1/$2/index.html;
}
```

Is that possible to shorten it to just 1 or 2 sections? Thanks!

Comment: Are the `$1` and `$2` terms intended to capture path elements (not including the `/` separator)? You can use one regular expression by making the captures less greedy or using a character class. For example: `^/t/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/`

Comment: @RichardSmith It worked! Please post it as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression location blocks are intended to capture the first two path elements following the `/t/` path element, and use them in identical `try_files` statements.

You can achieve the same functionality by restricting the scope of captures by making them less greedy (e.g. `(.*?)`) or by excluding the `/` separator with a character class (e.g. `([^/]+)`).

For example:

```
location ~ ^/t/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /t/$1/$2/index.html;
}
```

See [this document](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) for more.